# Can I connect two MC business units to one Salesforce org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

Hope someone has an answer for my question. We have two business units in Marketing Cloud and one Salesforce Org. With the MC Connector, we push the SF data to MC.

At moment we use an SQL query to transfer the data of the synchronized objects from the parent business unit to the child business unit.The total sync time for the child BU is +/- 1,5 hour.

Cloud we use multi org to set up the MC connector for the child BU?

Thanks in advance,

Klaas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can enable multi-org to connect multiple business units to the same Org, this is not supported and **not recommended**. Support will advise against this and can be problematic when synchronizing a large number of records, as multiple concurrent requests will be made on the same object from different BUs, which places a large (and unnecessary) load on the Object. Also, bear in mind that once you implement multi-org, this is irreversible as it changes the underlying structure of your account.

As you can't share Synchronized Data Extensions, you are correct in that you will need to write query activities to update DEs in your Child BU. FYI (and for the information of others who want to do this), you can retrieve Synchronized DEs directly from a Query Activity in the Child BU using the ENT. prefix (e.g. use `FROM ENT.Contact_Salesforce`).

**However**, you can't do this for accounts that were created after January 2018, as they have implemented a measure to prevent this (due to a GDPR policy update). But you can open a Support request asking them to enable this again for you.

Comment: Hi Eliot, 

Thanks for your answer! When we enable multi-org to connect multiple business units to the same Org. Do you know if the Salesforce canvas activities in the Journey Builder will work? 

Reagarding the large load on the object. We where thinking of adding an unique field to the object. This wil make it possible to filter on this field in the sync objects (MC -> Contact Builder -> Data Sources). So clients of BU1 will only sync to BU1 and clients of BU2 will only sync to BU2.

We already use the ENT. prefix, a great tip though! Makes it a lot easier. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multi-org account configuration allows individual Marketing Cloud business units to connect with a single Salesforce org, independent of the parent account or other business units.

In your case, both business units are connected to the same Sales Cloud Org, ORGA, using connected app authentication. A user, U1, has access to both business units. Because both business units are connected to ORGA, U1 must be connected to the same Sales Cloud user account, UA.

Comment: this seems to be the most up to date answer as to 2020. Can you confirm that with the above configuration (2 BUs connected to the same SF org with Multi-Org enabled) you are able to use Salesforce Canvas Activities (e.g. Update SF Contact) and Salesforce Data Entry in Journey Builder? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

New update from Salesforce official doc said this is possible:

**Multiple business units connected to a single org.**

**Note**
NOTE Multi-Org is available for Enterprise 2.0 accounts using version 5.494 or higher of the managed package. It requires Connected App Authentication and Custom Profile Centers. Not sure what type of account you have? Review Marketing Cloud editions for more information.

These best practices are recommended when configuring multi-org:

**1. Control access to the All Subscribers list.**
The Marketing Cloud All Subscribers list is a comprehensive list of all subscribers, even in a multi-org account. To prevent users from seeing subscribers outside of an org they can access, remove non-admin users’ access to All Subscribers and use Subscriber Business Unit Filters.

**2. Plan your business unit and user connections.**
While disconnecting accounts is supported, plan your Salesforce org to Marketing Cloud business unit and user connections carefully before implementation.

**3. Use dedicated API users.**
Assign each connected business unit a dedicated API user to reduce confusion after connecting. If multiple business units are connected to the same Salesforce org, use a shared API User.

**4. Use one version of the connector.**
When connecting your Marketing Cloud account with multiple orgs, use the same version of the connector in each connected org. For example, don’t use V2 in one Salesforce org and Marketing Cloud Connect (V5) in another Salesforce org.

**Warning**
WARNING If you use Synchronized Data Sources with multi-org configuration, when you disconnect a business unit from Sales or Service Cloud, synchronized data extension names can change. To ensure that they continue working, update query activities that reference those synchronized data extensions.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5